# Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null' Tomcat 9, Oracle 12c, JDK 8,

Tags: jax-ws, tomcat9, ojdbc

I have a simple web service that is trying to open a connection to the database.

I am using jax-ws, Oracle 12c DB, Tomcat 9, Java 8.

Can anyone post the correct way to do this?

So far I've downloaded ojdbc7.jar and ucp.jar into the $TOMCAT_HOME/lib directory.

1. What goes in applicationPath/META-INF/web.xml ?

Right now I have the following:

```
  <resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/UCPPool</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
  </resource-ref>
</web-app>
```

2. What goes in TOMCAT_HOME/conf/server.xml ?

Right now I have the following:

```
<context docbase="demods" path="/demods" reloadable="true">
  <Resource 
       name="jdbc/UCPPool"
       auth="Container"
       factory="oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl"
       type="oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSource"
       description="Pas testing UCP Pool in Tomcat"
       connectionFactoryClassName="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource"
       minPoolSize="2"
       maxPoolSize="5"
       inactiveConnectionTimeout="20"
       user="test"
       password="test"
       url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=oracleDB12c)(PORT=1563))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=PPS)))"
       connectionPoolName="UCPPool"
       validateConnectionOnBorrow="true"
       sqlForValidateConnection="select 1 from DUAL" />
 </context>
```

3. What goes in TOMCAT_HOME/conf/context.xml ?

   I don't have anything in this file right now.

Here is the code that I am using to setup the JDBC connection:

```
         Context ctx = new InitialContext();
         Context envContext = (Context) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env");
         DataSource ds  = (DataSource) envContext.lookup("jdbc/UCPPool");
         Connection conn = null;                         
         try {
             conn = ds.getConnection();
         }
         catch (SQLException e) { 
             return e.getMessage();
         }
```

The message returned by the web service is:

```
"Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does anyone have any idea on this? Thanks!

Comment: Is there any specific reason for using oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl in resource configuration? Also it seems you're not defining driverClassName property. Could you try to configure resource as described in tomcat documentation - https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html#Oracle_8i,_9i_&_10g using attributes type="javax.sql.DataSource" and  driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good news, I was able to get this to work today at the office.

Here is what I did:

1. I created a context.xml file and placed it in my eclipse project inside of META-INF/. In META-INF/context.xml I put the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xml>
<Context> 
<Resource 
        name="jdbc/orcljdbc_ds" 
        auth="Container"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
        driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
        username="user1"
        password="password"
        url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//myoracledb:1563/DEVSID"

/>
</Context>
```

I did not put anything in the Tomcat context.xml or server.xml file, but I think that you can for different scenarios (i.e.Shared datasource with multiple applications running on single application server). I also did not put anything in my Eclipse project WEB-INF\web.xml.

I used the following code to test the connection:

```
package planAdminWS;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;

import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.sql.*;
import javax.naming.*;

@WebService
public class PlanAdminWS {

    @WebMethod
     public String createPlan(String EIN, String PN)
     {
        return "Creating Plan: " + EIN + "/" + PN;
     }

    @WebMethod
    public String updatePlan(String EIN, String PN) throws NamingException, SQLException {
        // Get a context for the JNDI look up
        DataSource ds = getDataSource();
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            conn = ds.getConnection();
            if (conn != null) {
                Statement stmt = null;
                ResultSet rs = null;
                String query = "select * from V$version";
                stmt = conn.createStatement();
                rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                while (rs.next()) {
                    System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
                    return "Database Version : " + rs.getString(1);
                }
            } else {
                return "Conn is NULL";
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            return e.getMessage();
        }

        return "Could not get DB Version";
    }

     /*
      * Method to create a datasource after the JNDI lookup
      */

      private DataSource getDataSource() throws NamingException {
        Context ctx;
        ctx = new InitialContext();
        Context envContext = (Context) ctx.lookup("java:/comp/env");
        // Look up a data source
        javax.sql.DataSource ds
              = (javax.sql.DataSource) envContext.lookup ("jdbc/orcljdbc_ds");
        return ds;
      }
}
```

this returned the following in SoapUI:

"Database Version : Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production"

Thanks for the help!!!

Here was another good resource: https://www.journaldev.com/2513/tomcat-datasource-jndi-example-java

Answer (score 0):

Can you take a look at a [github example](https://github.com/oracle/oracle-db-examples/tree/master/java/jdbc/Tomcat_Servlet) and follow that to build your Tomcat applicaiton?